# How to display text after AlertDialog is closed

Tags: flutter

I try to code my first app in flutter. It shows a list of items then once tapped, shows the details.
When moved back - list of items is shown again, from where I can delete an item by tapping trash icon. Once the icon is tapped AlerDialog comes up to confirm action.
Here I have an issue... how to display a text 'No data to display' on empty list after AlertDialog is closed.

I do not know why this text is not displayed? Can you please advice?

```
setState(() {
  posts.removeAt(index);
  if(posts.isEmpty)
  {
    const Text("No data to display");   //  <---- WHY this text is NOT displayed
  }
});
```

the entire code looks more or less like this:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
        title: const Text('Some text'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: signUserOut,
            icon: const Icon(Icons.logout),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<List<Post>>(
          future: postsFuture,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const CircularProgressIndicator(
                backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.green)
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return buildPosts(snapshot.data!);
            } else {
              return const Text("No data to display");
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  Widget buildPosts(List<Post> posts) {
    return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: posts.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final post = posts[index];
            final List<ChartData> chartData = [
              ChartData('', post.proc!.toDouble(), Colors.green),
              ChartData(
                  '', (100.toDouble() - post.proc!.toDouble()), Colors.black),
            ];
            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                loadListDetails(post.id!, post.lista!);
              },
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.white,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 0),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 15),
                height: 150,
                width: double.maxFinite,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(...),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 2,
                      child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 2,
                              child: Row(
                                  children: [
                                    const Text(
                                        '       ', textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                            fontSize: 14,
                                            color: Colors.black)),
                                    IconButton(
                                      alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                                      onPressed: () async {
                                        final result = await showDialog<bool>(
                                          context: context,
                                          builder: (context) =>
                                              AlertDialog(
                                                title: const Text(
                                                    'Some text'),
                                                content: const Text(
                                                    'Some text ...'),
                                                actions: [
                                                  TextButton(
                                                    onPressed: () =>
                                                        Navigator.pop(
                                                            context, false),
                                                    child: const Text('Cancel'),
                                                  ),
                                                  TextButton(
                                                    onPressed: () =>
                                                        Navigator.pop(
                                                            context, true),
                                                    child: const Text('Delete'),
                                                  ),
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                        );

                                        if (result == null || !result) {
                                          return;
                                        }
                                        deleteList(post.id!, post.loginEmail!);
                                        print('removing postid[$index]');
                                        setState(() {
                                          posts.removeAt(index);
                                          if(posts.isEmpty)
                                            {
                                              const Text("No data to display");   //  <---- WHY this text is NOT displayed
                                            }
                                        });
                                      },
                                      iconSize: 20.0,
                                      icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
                                    ),
                                  ]
                              ),
                            ),
                            Expanded(...),
                            const Expanded(...)
                          ]
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check post data empty or not. If post data is empty no need to call `buildPosts(snapshot.data!)`. At that time show Simple text or empty UI. please check the fixed code below.

```
 body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<List<Post>>(
          future: postsFuture,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const CircularProgressIndicator(
                backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.green)
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                // Store Post data in posts variable
                List<Post> posts = snapshot.data??[];
                //Check if posts is Empty show No data message. 
                //posts empty means hav't any post data
                if(posts.isEmpty){
                 return const Text("No data to display");
                }
                return buildPosts(snapshot.data!);
            } else {
              return const Text("No data to display");
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Replace your setState with

```
 deleteList(post.id!, post.loginEmail!);
  print('removing postid[$index]');
  setState(() {
  posts.removeAt(index);
  });
```